# training agents inside pages, esp for voice based input

Tags: dialogflow-cx

I need to capture an alphanumeric key from a caller (8 digit combo of numerals and alphabets), the test simulator works fine, but on the voice (integrated with a third party contact center IVR)the detection never happens. Further this parameter is captured within a page as a mandatory parameter, i am not able to train it  as we do in intents. Any counsel is appreciated

New to CX, ES it was easy as everything happened in the intents itself

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.